# Convert Local IP address to Integer

Tags: php, ip

In my program I will convert user ip to integer with `ip2long()`, everything is ok on internet. but when I run on my local network with 192.168.1.* ip, the returned value is wrong and I cannot store in MySQL.

for example:

```
echo ip2long('192.168.1.13'); // 3221225472
```

Comment: 32-bit PHP versus 64-bit PHP and PHP_INT_MAX and signed longs

Answer (score 0):

When [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) creates a long from an IP address, say a.b.c.d, it uses the following formula:

> a x 256^3 + b x 256^2 + c x 256^1 + d x 256^0

You could retrieve the original IP address by reversing this operation, of course, but it is much easier to use the PHP function [long2ip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php).